# Doctrine2 - Save number as negative value

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, doctrine

I have a class which saves invoices - credits and charges. I have two ORM\Entity classes -- `Charge` and `Credit` -- which are stored in the same table using an `ORM\DiscriminatorMap`

```
/**  
 * @ORM\Table(name="transaction")  
 * @ORM\InheritanceType("SINGLE_TABLE")  
 * @ORM\DiscriminatorColumn(name="type", type="string")  
 * @ORM\DiscriminatorMap({  
 *   "charge" = "Charge",  
 *   "credit" = "Credit"
 * })   
 */ 
 abstract class Transaction {

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="decimal")
     */
    private $value; 
 }
```

I want charges to be stored in the table as positive numbers, and credits to be stored as negative, so that I can easily write SQL aggregate functions to get the SUM of the account, which will take into account both charges and credits without any work.

However, I want $credit->setValue() to receive positive numbers, and $credit->getValue() to return positive numbers, so that it will be easier to work with on the app side.
In short, I want only the negative value when *storing* the data for credits, but all positive when *working* with the data.

How can I have doctrine convert the value to negative (for credits) only when writing to the DB (and revert when reading)? 
Is this bad practice? Any better solutions welcome.

Comment: how about your getter (e.g. `getValue()`) returns the absolute value of the returned value like `return abs($this->value);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just modifying your getter and setter for `Credit` should work:

```
public function getValue(){
  // always positive
  return abs($this->value);
} 

public function setValue(\float $val){
  // always negative
  $this->value = 0 - abs($val);
}
```

Comment: I was worried this wouldn't work with de/serialization but it works!

Comment: hey cool, thanks for taking my answer and getting the credit.

Comment: sorry @craigh, that's not what happened I was already writing up my answer when you posted a comment. If you wished to post an answer why did you post a comment?

Comment: it's not a big deal. no problem. best wishes :D